# Mocking a method which takes temporary file as input

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a code like below:

```
public start() {
    ..............
    ..............
    ImpAbc abc = extract(ImplObj);
    ...............
}

public ImpAbc extract(Impl ImplObj) {
    ................
    File BuildPath = File.createTempFile("xyz", ".zip");
    ImpAbc abc = ImplObj.downloadImp(Integer.parseInt(rev.trim()), BuildPath,
                conn);  
    .................
    return abc;
}
```

I am testing the method `start()` which calls `extract()` method. I want to mock the method `downloadImp(..)` as it is a 3rd party API and internally calls many other method.

But the problem is `downloadImp(..)` takes a temporary file as input, and when I use `when().thenReturn()` like below, it doesn't calls mocked method, as the temporary file has a unique name each time.

What I tried is:

```
Impl mockImplObj = mock(Impl.class);
ImpAbc mockImpAbc = mock(ImpAbc.class);
when(mockImplObj.downloadImp(Integer.parseInt(rev.trim()), File.createTempFile("xyz", ".zip"),
                mockconn).thenReturn(mockImpAbc);
```

Can anyone help in resolving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any:

```
import org.mockito.Matchers;
```

...

```
when(mockImplObj.downloadImp(Integer.parseInt(rev.trim()), Matchers.any(File.class)).thenReturn(mockImpAbc);
```

Comment: I tried this. Thank you. It is working with small changes that if I want to pass one arg as Matchers then all arguments should be passed as Matchers. ex when(mockImplObj.downloadImp(Matchers.any(Integer.class),Matchers.any(File.class),Matchers.any(ConnectionParams.class)).thenReturn(mockImpAbc);

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is that you have a static dependency on `File.createTempFile`, and static dependencies are a death-knell to unit testing with mocks.

Create the temp file outside of `extract()` and pass it in.

```
public start() {
    ...
    File buildPath = File.createTempFile("xyz", ".zip");
    ImpAbc abc = extract(ImplObj, buildPath);
}

public ImpAbc extract(Impl ImplObj, File buildPath) {
    ...
    ImpAbc abc = ImplObj.downloadImp(Integer.parseInt(rev.trim()), buildPath,
            conn);  
    ...
    return abc;
}
```

Now there's no dependency on `File.createTempFile` in your method under test.